# How can I get the time and frequency resolution from wavelet?

Tags: matlab, wavelet, time-frequency

I've got a little issue understanding wavelet analysis. I report a code from Matlab tutorial
figure;

```
s0  = 6*dt;  ds = 0.15;  NbSc = 50;
wname = 'morl';
SCA = {s0,ds,NbSc};
cwtsig = cwtft({Y,dt},'scales',SCA,'wavelet',wname);
MorletFourierFactor = 4*pi/(6+sqrt(2+6^2));
Scales = cwtsig.scales.*MorletFourierFactor;
Freq = 1./Scales;
imagesc(t,[],abs(cwtsig.cfs));
indices = get(gca,'ytick');
set(gca,'yticklabel',Freq(indices));
xlabel('Time'); ylabel('Hz');
title('Time-Frequency Analysis with CWT');
```

I know that the Morlet Fourier Factor it's a key parameter for the anaylsis. We know that for each scale (or frequency) the wavelet can change shape becoming narrower or broader as well. 
Can I derive the time and frequency resolution knowing ,the Morlet Fourier Factor, at each frequencies step?
thank you